# How to add content inside Array using forEach to innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how can I add data content inside array to innerHTML using the forEach?

For some reason, It is not showing up. Is this possible to do? I am working with dynamic data this way I need to loop through my data and show them with innerHTML.

```
const showPosts = (data, value) => {
    const btnDiscover = document.querySelector('[data-show="discover"]');

    const slides = data.add_post_slides;

    const Posts = () => {
        slides.length > 0 &&
            slides
                .forEach((el) => {
                    return <h2>123</h2>;
                })
                .join('');
    };

    // console.log(Posts());

    btnDiscover.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        body.classList.add('toggle-legend', 'no-scroll');

        console.log('Discover clicked');
        console.log(slides);

        theContent = `
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal__body">
                <a href="#" id="close"><span class="modal__close"></span></a>

                ${Posts()}
            </div>
        </div>
        `;

        timelineModal.innerHTML = theContent;

        onModalClose();
    });
};
```

How can I do such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many way. I can suggest pick the element by using **getElementById**. After that create a function that will add the data in innerHtml of that element. Try to do something similar below

```
var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "cherry"];
fruits.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += index + ":" + item + "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

forEach don't return responses. use `Array.map` or declare and initialize array variables and then push them.

```
const newSlides = slides.map((el) => el)
```

or

```
const elements = [];
slides.forEach((el) => elements.push(el));
```

```
// Add return. your arrow function don't return element.
const Posts = () => {
    return slides.length > 0 &&
        slides
            .forEach((el) => {
                return <h2>123</h2>;
            })
            .join('');
};
```

Comment: Your code have problem in Posts. because it isn't emit element. add `return`.